# youtube plugin for traffic monitoring using bro IDS

Tags: security, youtube, bro

I have configured bro latest version by its [quickstart](https://www.bro.org/sphinx/quickstart/index.html) guide. I have to monitor youtube users statistics. Default plugins in base/* are loaded by default. By running bro with default setting does not provides youtube statitics i.e. connection , ip address etc. I have found a script in `policy/misc/app-stats/plugins/youtube.bro`, I think it should be loaded. But I have not found its complete details.

My questions are

```
Where I am wrong.
How to load a script (youtube.bro in mycase).
```

Answer (score 2):

Loading scripts not in base can be done via the file `local.bro`.
Assuming your bro installation is in `/usr/local/` the full path would be `/usr/local/bro/share/bro/site/`. You should have that file already there with some examples in it. Just add your script using the `@load` statement, e.g., `@load misc/app-stats/plugins/youtube`.

If you just want to run your script on a traffic sample to try it out you can always go with

> bro -r your-traffic-sample.pcap your-script.bro

Comment: I have followd above steps and run youtube scripts. But still there is no info in http.log. While tcpdump data contains youtube packects info.

Comment: I just looked into that script. It is part of the sumstats framework. All it does is adding youtube stats to sumstats. In order to see something you need to combine it with the framework. The following links go to documentation and examples:
https://www.bro.org/sphinx/frameworks/sumstats.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aj5FRoHF6Qo
http://try.bro.org/#/trybro?example=sumstats
https://www.bro.org/sphinx/scripts/policy/misc/app-stats/main.bro.html